# Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' on joomla backend

Tags: mysql, joomla

Since yesterday I have this fault when I am calling the url www.mysite.com/administrator and I get this error message:

```
Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY' SQL=INSERT INTO irnfl_updates (extension_id, name, element, type, version) VALUES (10000, 'JSN Template Framework', 'jsntplframework', 'plugin', '2.3.6')
```

What is the fault? How I can resolve this?

Comment: This is not really a development question: there's a Stack Exchange site dedicated to Joomla: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This probably means that the primary key field in your irnfl_updates table should be defined as auto_increment and it's not. To fix it, just alter the table and enable the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

When loading your administrator page, Joomla checks for updates to the installed extensions. The updates table got somehow corrupted, or there's a bug in the update stream for that specific extension.
You have several possible solutions.

- Open System -> Clear Cache, clear everything, then go to Extensions -> Extension Manager -> Updates and click on "Find updates". This should reset your problem.
- Manually truncate the "irnfl_updates" table from phpMyAdmin or similar tool. It will be repopulated anyway.
- Remove the "jsntplframework" plugin and reinstall. Please make a backup first, and be sure you are able to restore it if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to create a full backup of the current situation.

Use phpMyAdmin to solve it directly in your database: 
go to the #__users table.
Check the highest ID (e.g. 987).

Under [Operations] you can under "Table Options" set the AUTO_INCREMENT.
Set it to the highest ID + 1 (e.g. 988).